# How to convert string to number and keep string if it's not a number in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I tried several methods (Number, parseFloat, *1) of string to number conversion but everytime I can't get desired value:

```js
var str = ["0.20", "day"];
var num;

str.forEach(v => {
  num = parseFloat(v);
  console.log(num);
})
```

How can I get 0.2 as a number and "day" as a string [0.2, "day"] in the result?

Comment: You should rephrase your question. *How to convert string to number in javascript?* you answered that yourself in your own question. Your real question is something else, so express that.

Comment: Done! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the parsed value is not a number (NaN). If so, print the string as it is, otherwise convert it.

`l = parseFloat(v)` Here I try to convert the value to float and assign the result to the variable `l`

`isNaN()` Is the built in method that checks if a certain result is not a number and is what I use to check if variable `l` is a number or not.

`?` is a ternary operator

`v` is printed if it is not a number (if it is NaN)

Otherwise `l` (which is the parsed value) is printed

```js
var str = ["0.20", "day"];

console.log(
  str.map(v => isNaN(l = parseFloat(v))? v : l)
)

/* A shorter way is to do */

console.log(
  str.map(v=>+v||v)
)
```

Comment: thank you. Could you explain what does `l = parseFloat(v))? v : l` mean?